# How to remove white border around a chart?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

This is slightly modified code of `org.jfree.chart.demo.BarChartDemo1`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();

                JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

                //chart.setBorderVisible(false); // no effect
                //chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)); // no effect

                ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
                chartPanel.setFillZoomRectangle(true);
                chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
                //chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
                chartPanel.setBounds(100,100,640,480);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setLayout(null);
                //frame.setContentPane(chartPanel);
                frame.add(chartPanel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
```

it draws

[image]

Is it possible to remove that white border around a chart? Some tries are in code, which had no effect.

Comment: Try using a layout manager instead of setting the bounds

Comment: This was to localize effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as you have already eliminated the domain and range axes, there remains one more source of padding that you have not accounted for. You are missing this:

```
chart.getPlot().setInsets( new RectangleInsets(){
        public void trim( Rectangle2D area ) {};
    });
```

The empty space you see in your posted example is due to `Plot` insets where your posted code is manipulating the `JFreeChart`. The reason for the anonymous subclass in the solution code is to eliminate a 1-pixel "halo" in the original implementation.

EDIT:

I fiddled around a bit more and noticed you may or may not need this in addition to the inset fix. I haven't poked around too deeply in this, but passing in a sub-classed `CategoryPlot` appears to do the trick for this specialized case at the very least.

```
private class WrappedCategoryPlot extends CategoryPlot
{
  @Override
  protected AxisSpace calculateAxisSpace( Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D plotArea )
  {
     return new AxisSpace();
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. Does the second alteration help when used with the original answer?

Comment: You were generally right. The problem was theme affected the layout.